# Multiple email input get populated by autofill with different name/id/placeholder

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, autofill

In a form with multiple email-inputs with different name, id & placeholder, chrome autofills always 9 fields at a time. Of course, I could disable autofill (with `autocomplete="new-password"`), which solves the problem.

But what can I do, that the user **can choose** multiple different emails from his autofill?

```html
<form action="">
    <input type="email" name="email1" id="mail-1" placeholder="Mail of Person #1">
    <input type="email" name="email2" id="mail-2" placeholder="Mail of Person #2">
    <input type="email" name="email3" id="mail-3" placeholder="Mail of Person #3">
    <input type="email" name="email4" id="mail-4" placeholder="Mail of Person #4">
    <input type="email" name="email5" id="mail-5" placeholder="Mail of Person #5">
    <input type="email" name="email6" id="mail-6" placeholder="Mail of Person #6">
    <input type="email" name="email7" id="mail-7" placeholder="Mail of Person #7">
    <input type="email" name="email8" id="mail-8" placeholder="Mail of Person #8">
    <input type="email" name="email9" id="mail-9" placeholder="Mail of Person #9">
    <input type="email" name="email10" id="mail-10" placeholder="Mail of Person #10">
</form>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xhtv781s/
Demo with array naming: https://jsfiddle.net/1kuvfasq/

[image: screencast]

*Tested on macOS 10.15.7 / Chrome 92.*

Comment: I've disabled autofill in all my browsers, so I have to ask: is the email address the same in all the auto-filled fields?

Comment: I don't think what you're exactly looking to do is possible.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica yes - all the same, check the screen gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have edited your HTML code to fix this. Allow me to explain.

```html
<form action="">
    <input autocomplete="nofill" type="email" name="email1" id="mail-1" placeholder="Mail of Person #1">
    <input autocomplete="nofill" type="email" name="email2" id="mail-2" placeholder="Mail of Person #2">
    <input autocomplete="nofill" type="email" name="email3" id="mail-3" placeholder="Mail of Person #3">
    <input autocomplete="nofill" type="email" name="email4" id="mail-4" placeholder="Mail of Person #4">
    <input autocomplete="nofill" type="email" name="email5" id="mail-5" placeholder="Mail of Person #5">
    <input autocomplete="nofill" type="email" name="email6" id="mail-6" placeholder="Mail of Person #6">
    <input autocomplete="nofill" type="email" name="email7" id="mail-7" placeholder="Mail of Person #7">
    <input autocomplete="nofill" type="email" name="email8" id="mail-8" placeholder="Mail of Person #8">
    <input autocomplete="nofill" type="email" name="email9" id="mail-9" placeholder="Mail of Person #9">
    <input autocomplete="nofill" type="email" name="email10" id="mail-10" placeholder="Mail of Person #10">
</form>
```

With google chrome, all you had to do back then was add `autocomplete=false` to the  tag and it would not add autocorrect to sections of your form. The current fix for this is to put `autocomplete="nofill"` to each of your  tags.

Now you can change the nofill to whatever you want because that confuses google chrome and disables autocomplete on the  you place that attribute in.

As far as I know to, [This is a bug that was reported a long time ago.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c164)

Comment: Thanks for that. Works fine as expeced. Once again, a feature which is neither in the MDN nor on google docs officially to find. https://developers.google.com/s/results/web?q=nofill / https://developer.mozilla.org/en/search?q=nofill

Comment: The reason I used 'nofill' in the text is so then google chrome does not autocomplete. It is not an attribute itself but is a temporary bug/fix that rectifies the situation. I did look for other solutions, but with the time given, this is the best one I can recommend until Google's dev team fixes this.